# Can employers see when a user favorites a job posting?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Can employers see when a user designates a job posting as a favorite, when clicking the favorite star button? If so, what are the rules governing when this is seen versus not seen?

I'm curious if this is a passive "hello employer, you're interesting", or, if this is merely a tool for the user to bookmark a posting, similar to questions in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, they cannot see your favorite jobs.

We do not have any plans to change the behavior of how this works.

**Source:** I am a developer on the Talent team here at Stack Overflow, and deeply familiar with the employer side of things.